# Air drop: buttons don't react to click when sharing from a Finder window

Tags: finder, bug, airdrop

I am not be able to start the transfer properly using Airdrop, despite seeing the other devices without problem.

## What I do:

1. Open a folder with Finder
2. Select a bunch of files
3. Right click > share... > AirDrop
4. The Finder window becomes darker behind the "Airdrop" popup
5. Click on a device

Now, the Finder window and the Airdrop popup move right to the top left corner of the screen. At that point, I can't click on buttons anymore. I can't close the window, I can't click on "Cancel", I can't click on devices anymore.

## What I have found

- Using the keyboard, I can navigate to the "Cancel" button and close the popup by pressing space.
- Alternatively, if I enable the "Full Keyboard Access" in the Accessibility settings, I can see that the buttons are actually outside of the popup. It's like the zone responsive to clicks stayed in place when the window moved to the top left corner (see attached images).

## Conclusion

This is very annoying. This problem does not happen if I share from another place or by another mean. For instance, if I right-click on a file on my desktop, I can use the Airdrop popup without problems. It is safe to assume that the Finder window is not supposed to move, and that could be the problem. Whatever resets its coordinates to (0,0) prevents the buttons to react to my clicks.

What's wrong with Finder? How can I use Airdrop like it is supposed to work?

Macbook Air, M1 2020 with Ventura 13.2.1
[image: Three buttons of the Airdrop popup outside of the Airdrop popup. The active zone of the button is indicated in blue on the screenshot thanks to Apple's Full Keyboard Access feature. The visual buttons are far away.]